# What is the best way to parse a xml file without xmlns?

Tags: java, xml, dom

For reason beyond my control, I must parse a xml without xmlns tag. I believe that it is a bad practice because it miss namespace control. Anyway, I must program for such scenario. What could be the best way to face it? I try setNamespaceAware = false and it does work for file without xmlns tag but it seems that it doesn't work properly when reading xml with xmlns tag. Plus this, I guess that by setting any awareness configuration to false isn't a good practice. I read some article telling to add the xmlns to the file programmatically but I am in doubt if it might be a good option. Any comment will be appreciated.

```
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory fac = new org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl();
fac.setNamespaceAware(true);
org.w3c.dom.Document d = null;
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder builder = fac.newDocumentBuilder();
d = builder.parse("C:/my_folder/my_file.xml");


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<c:de format="N" lengthField="0" maxLength="012" minLength="012" name="AMOUNT, TRANSACTION" number="004" subFields="00"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the statements that I use to parse a XML file

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dfactory.setNamespaceAware(false);
dfactory.setValidating(false);
DocumentBuilder bldr = dfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
bldr.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
    public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        // ignore warnings
    }

    public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
            // ignore parse validation errors
    }

    public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
            throw exception;
    }
});
Document doc = bldr.parse(new InputSource(is));
```

I think you need to turn validation off if you turn namespace off.

There really is nothing wrong with using XML this way.  Namespace help with a specific kind of evolution of the schema, but not all kinds, and if you analyze it far enough, namespace only delays the problem, but does not actually solve the problem.  It depends on the specific XML, and some are managed in a way that requires the name space.  But have no guilt if the XML is not managed this way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know the difference between " ... new org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl();" and " ... DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();"? there isn't such option "setNamespaceAware" in the code that I start to mantain because it is coded with xerces.

Answer (score 0):

If a schema can be created for a file, create that schema (without targetNamespace attribute, that means, target namespace is ""), generate classes (for example with xjc/JAXB) and parse.

Comment: In such cases I sometimes create a schema WITH targetNamespace and fix XML before giving it to XML mapping library.

Comment: Thank you dor your ansewer but I didn't understand your suggestion. The application receives a lot of xml files from other application which I don't have control. Are you suggesting that I created a XSD file for each type of xml that I can receive? If so, what will this help me? I guess that I will have to edit the xml file anyway.